apollo client failed to fetch but simple fetch from the same url works
i am trying to implement a graphql client / server in my private lan.
i am using apolloclient 3 and apollo server 3.
for some reason the client fails to query the server.
a simple fetch from the same server works fine.
There are no error in the server terminal
Chrome shows two errors

net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Uncaught (in promise) ApolloError: Failed to fetch
Stacktraces below

    // fails 

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      uri: "http://191.168.11.121:3502",
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    
    client
      .query({
        query: gql`
          query GetBooks {
            books {
              title
              author
            }
          }
        `,
      })
      .then((result) => console.log(result));

    // works
    
    fetch("http://192.168.11.121:3502", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: `
          query GetBooks {
            books {
              title
              author
            }
          }
        `,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res));

 POST http://191.168.11.121:3502/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
(anonymous) @   createHttpLink.ts:188
Subscription    @   module.js:190
subscribe   @   module.js:264
complete    @   Concast.ts:218
Concast.start   @   Concast.ts:109
Concast @   Concast.ts:86
QueryManager.getObservableFromLink  @   QueryManager.ts:1114
QueryManager.getResultsFromLink @   QueryManager.ts:1165
resultsFromLink @   QueryManager.ts:1597
QueryManager.fetchQueryByPolicy @   QueryManager.ts:1632
fromVariables   @   QueryManager.ts:1275
QueryManager.fetchConcastWithInfo   @   QueryManager.ts:1337
QueryManager.fetchQuery @   QueryManager.ts:629
QueryManager.query  @   QueryManager.ts:782
ApolloClient.query  @   ApolloClient.ts:455
./src/index.js  @   index.js:20
options.factory @   react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:22
(anonymous) @   startup:7
(anonymous) @   startup:7
Show less

index.ts:126 Uncaught (in promise) ApolloError: Failed to fetch
    at new ApolloError (index.ts:126:1)
    at QueryManager.ts:1221:1
    at both (asyncMap.ts:30:1)
    at asyncMap.ts:17:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.then (asyncMap.ts:17:1)
    at Object.error (asyncMap.ts:34:1)
    at notifySubscription (module.js:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229:1)
Caused by: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at createHttpLink.ts:188:1
    at new Subscription (module.js:190:1)
    at Observable.subscribe (module.js:264:1)
    at Object.complete (Concast.ts:218:1)
    at Concast.start (Concast.ts:109:1)
    at new Concast (Concast.ts:86:1)
    at QueryManager.getObservableFromLink (QueryManager.ts:1114:1)
    at QueryManager.getResultsFromLink (QueryManager.ts:1165:1)
    at resultsFromLink (QueryManager.ts:1597:1)
    at QueryManager.fetchQueryByPolicy (QueryManager.ts:1632:1)


What is the error message it fails with? What's in console.log on the server?

added error messages to the question

Hmm, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT doesn't sound like a client-side problem as long as you're 100% sure that the IP/port are correct. Anything in the server logs?

after changing the code to use the same const for the server url in both places it works now. Wth? After changing it back to use the string , it still works. Must have been a cache or compiler hickup. Closing. Ty anyways

Glad to hear it worked out in the end :)
